# How can I sum all these counts in php laravel query and then display in php?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

this is the code where finding count and taking first records now I need to add all these values. Thanks

```
    $audio = \App\Models\audiodata::where('u_id', $u_id)->count();
    $credentialdata = \App\Models\credentialdata::where('u_id', $u_id)->count();
    $connection = \App\Models\Connectiondata::where('u_id', $u_id)->first();
    $image = \App\Models\imagedata::where('u_id', $u_id)->first();
```

for e.g:

```
$audio + $credentialdata
(int)$audio + (int)$credentialdata
```

but these two didn't work in my case it says object cannot be converted to int

Comment: $audio + $credentialdata ? I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: yes i'm trying to add these values but adding this way gives me error(unsupported operand types:int  +) and while using (int)$audio + (int)$credentialdata this gives me (object could not be converted to int). Any help is appreciated. @misterdebug

Comment: not possible, count returns an int. try dd($audio); and tell me what you have :)

Comment: no problems with $audio problem occurs when adding +$audio+$connection+$image, sorry for that. @misterdebug

Comment: it's normal you get the first element with ->first(), you must ->count() like others $image = \App\Models\imagedata::where('u_id', $u_id)->count();